# How to fix section background color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I apologize for my errors with this post earlier. I'm having trouble understanding why my Small-bio section's background color isn't changing. I feel that it has something to do with the bootstrap carousel but idk. I want to be able to understand what I'm doing wrong and how to avoid this happening again. any help would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

I've tried changing other section's colors and changing the height and I've moved the style sheets.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Bagwell Productions</title>

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
      <!-- Google Font -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- CSS & bootstrap stylesheet -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bagwell\style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


      <!-- JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





    </head>

    <body>


      <section id="navbar">
        <!-- Nav Bar -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bagwell Productions</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact Me</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </section>



      <section id="slideshow">


        <!-- slideshow -->
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="C:\Users\ghost\Desktop\Projects\Bagwell\wetransfer-876787\126A0171.JPG" alt="league of extraordinary women" style="width:100%" style="height:auto" ; class="d-block w-100">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="C:\Users\ghost\Desktop\Projects\Bagwell\wetransfer-876787\IMG_3732.JPG" alt="Grad Pics" style="width:100%" ; style="height:auto" class="d-block w-100">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="C:\Users\ghost\Desktop\Projects\Bagwell\wetransfer-95bb54\IMG_9997.JPG" alt="pit bull" style="width:100%;" style="height:auto" "class=" d-block w-100"">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="C:\Users\ghost\Desktop\Projects\Bagwell\wetransfer-95bb54\IMG_7098.JPG" style="width:100%;" style="height:auto" class="d-block w-100">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="C:\Users\ghost\Desktop\Projects\Bagwell\wetransfer-876787\IMG_1938.JPG" alt="walking" style="width:100%;" style="height:auto" class="d-block w-100">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="C:\Users\ghost\Desktop\Projects\Bagwell\wetransfer-876787\IMG_1749.JPG" alt="nasa grad" style="width:100%;" style="height:auto" class="d-block w-100">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- controls for slideshow -->
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </section>

        <!-- Small intro -->
      <section id="small-bio">

        <div class="Bottom-intro">
          <h3>Welcome to the photography portfolio of William Bagwell. the Gallery's in this website showcase professional work in different settings.</h3>



        </div>

      </section>
    </body>

    </html>
```

````
    #small-bio{
      background-color: blue  !important;
    }
    #slideshow{
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #slideshow{
      overflow: auto;

    }

    }
    h3{
    background-color: blue;
    }

    .carousel-inner{
      overflow: ;
      padding-bottom: 7%;
      background-color: red;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .Bottom-intro{
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 300px;
      width: 100%;
      color:#fff;
      background-color: #ef8172;
      text-align: center;
    }

```
````

Comment: `I have a div that's background color isn't changing` <<-- Which div? Your code seems to be working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/4m52k8vf/

Answer (score 0):

look at your style.css linking

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bagwell\style.css">
```

correct it to

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bagwell/style.css">
```

may it help

Comment: thanks for your input @ashad however, this had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are trying to set a background color to a carousal where the image is taking up 100% of your container space (i.e. carousel-inner).

If you want a background-color for your container, reduce the size of the image to 80% maybe and give margin: 0 auto to the images so they can be center aligned.

Also you have mentioned redundant widths to images, 1) by adding w-100, 2) by using inline width. Use any one. And you have used 2 style tag in the elements which is incorrect.

Eg using inline style

`<img src="C:\Users\ghost\Desktop\Projects\Bagwell\wetransfer-95bb54\IMG_7098.JPG" style="width:80%; margin: 0 auto; height: auto" class="d-block">`

Eg using bootstrap classes

`<img src="C:\Users\ghost\Desktop\Projects\Bagwell\wetransfer-95bb54\IMG_7098.JPG" style="height:auto" class="d-block w-75 mx-auto">`

Do this for every image tag and you should have a background color behind your image.

Comment: lyer thanks so much for the help. so I changed my images using the bootstrap class you mentioned. The images did center align however the background color still won't change.

Comment: Haha, yeah I thought you had issues with your carousel. Well you have a space between background color blue and !important in your #small-bio style. Remove it and that should work. I.e. background-color: blue!important;

Comment: lyer sadly still no change.

Comment: If you check your css, there is an additional '}' closing curly braces. Can you try removing that?

Comment: lyer I removed the } and still nothing. I ended up removing all css except the.carousel-inner and. Bottom-intro and it's still not changing. It has to be smething with the carousel overriding my css but Idk how.

Comment: Can you put everything in a codepen or jsfiddle and share a link. I think directly looking at it would make sense.

Comment: lyer ok so I think I might have found the problem. while inputting my code into codepen i noticed that I was able to see the background color because the pictures didn't show up because I have them locally. So I changed my links to picture from the internet and everything showed up fine. so my guess is that its because I'm saving the pictures locally.